# Android NDK C Preprocessor Define for TARGET_PLATFORM

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

I would like to determine during compile time what the specified TARGET_PLATFORM has been specified.

As an example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
#if (TARGET_PLATFORM == 21)
#include <sys/system_properties.h>
#else
#include <sys/_system_properties.h>
#endif
```

I would prefer an ndk built-in preprocessor, but other alternatives are also welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <android/api-level.h>
#if __ANDROID_API__ == 21
....
#else
....
#endif
```